# Scrolling between dates in android

Tags: android

I am working on a project where i have to horizontally scroll between dates.I don't want to use a date picker.I would like to have two arrows for previous and next buttons.When i click on the next button the next date should be shown.Also each time a new date is selected i want to call a web service by passing the particular date.How do i go about doing this?

I have considered using a horizontal date picker library but i am not satisfied with the solutions which i am finding on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ViewPager for the same.

Comment: But i want to use it for a particular range of dates with  next and previous buttons.Is it possible?Any tutorial on the net?

Comment: Yes you have to add that particular items in adapter and set that adapter to viewPager